# Implementing -WhatIf in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm implementing a function that using the `SupportsShouldProcess` cmdletbinding and I'm having trouble understanding some of the resulting behavior.

Consider the following code --

```
foreach ($f in $filesToMove) {
                    $currAction = "Move File"
                    if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($f.ServerRelativeUrl, $currAction)) {
                        Move-PnPFile -SourceUrl $f.ServerRelativeUrl -TargetUrl $targetFolderPath -Force
                    }
                    [PSCustomObject]@{
                        SiteTitle         = $subSite.Title
                        SiteURL           = $subSite.Url
                        SourceRelativeUrl = $f.ServerRelativeUrl
                        TargetFolderPath  = $targetFolderPath
                        Action            = $currAction
                    } | Export-Csv -Path $logPath -Append
                }
```

The output I'm getting when running the function with `-whatif` is as follows --

```
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "/sites/abcd/investments/AATest1/Documents/Accounting Files/Test Document 1.docx".
What if: Performing the operation "Export-Csv" on target ".\logs\20240122T1405405677 - Move-FromAccountingFilesToReportsReceived.csv".
```

What I'm having trouble understanding is why I'm getting the second line of "What if" output.  It seems to me that I should only be getting the first line; anyway, that's my desired output.  I would like the `Export-Csv` cmdlet to run normally, which is why I placed it outside of the if() conditional block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing the (unfortunate) side effect of an *implementation detail*:

- When you pass a [common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters) such as `-WhatIf` to an [advanced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) function or script, PowerShell automatically translates it into a function/script-local [preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables) with the equivalent effect, such as `$WhatIfPreference = 'Continue'`.
- It is therefore *all* commands called from your function/script that see this preference and potentially honor it; in your case, it is the `Export-Csv` call that does.
- However, you should only be making the `Export-Csv` call if the `$PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($f.ServerRelativeUrl, $currAction)` returns `$true`, so as to make *all* actions performed by your function/script conditional on whether `-WhatIf` was passed or not.
- If you move the `Export-Csv` inside the `if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($f.ServerRelativeUrl, $currAction)) { ... }` statement, you then potentially face a similar problem, namely when [`-Confirm`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-confirm) is used (support for which is *also* implied by [`[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-shouldprocess), alongside `-WhatIf`), which is translated to a local [`$ConfirmPreference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#confirmpreference) `= 'Low'` variable, which both `Move-PnPFile` and `Export-Csv` would honor too, resulting in *three* confirmation prompts per object.

  - One option - albeit cumbersome and error prone - is to pass  `-Confirm:$false` to each and every call to another command that supports `SupportsShouldProcess` and therefore `-Confirm`.
  - A more robust - but still somewhat cumbersome - solution is to wrap the calls to other commands in `& { ... }` so as to execute them in a *child* [scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Scopes), in which you can safely set `$ConfirmPreference = 'None'` to prevent confirmation prompts from commands in that scope and its descendent scopes) *only* - see below.

    - However, this approach won't work if any of the commands inside the block happen to be commands that are also *advanced functions* but defined in a (different) *module*; those still require individual `-Confirm:$false` arguments, for the reasons explained below.

```bash
foreach ($f in 1..3) {
  $currAction = "Move File"
  if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($f.ServerRelativeUrl, $currAction)) {
     # Perform the operation(s) in a child scope, so as to limit
     # the effects of setting $ConfirmPreference to that scope.
      & {
        # Now that the intent to proceed unconditionally is implied,
        # prevent further prompts.
        $ConfirmPreference = 'None'
        Move-PnPFile -SourceUrl $f.ServerRelativeUrl -TargetUrl $targetFolderPath -Force
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            SiteTitle         = $subSite.Title
            SiteURL           = $subSite.Url
            SourceRelativeUrl = $f.ServerRelativeUrl
            TargetFolderPath  = $targetFolderPath
            Action            = $currAction
        } |
          Export-Csv -Path $logPath -Append
      }
  }
}
```

As an aside:

- As demonstrated, the by-design translation of common parameters to scope-local preference variables is problematic in practice.
- A related problem is that preference variables intentionally set *by the caller* - as an alternative to passing common parameters - aren't honored *across module boundaries* - see [GitHub issue #4568](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4568).